# Looping + Field in Fields + Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am quite new to python. In SQL its possible to create a loop function such as

fields = ['COL2','COL3']

for field in fields:
Sql query.

I want to replicate it with Python, but struggle to find the right way.

```
df
    COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
0   aaa     a1234   b1234   5
1   aaa     a2345   b2345   10
2   aaa     a3456   b3456   15
3   aaa     a5678   b5678   20
4   bbb     a5678   b5678   25

            
                
Preferred outcome.  

0   COL2    aaa bbb Grand Total
1   a1234   5       5
2   a2345   10      10
3   a3456   15      15
4   a5678   20  25  45
                
                
                
0   COL3    aaa bbb Grand Total
1   b1234   5       5
2   b2345   10      10
3   b3456   15      15
4   b5678   20  25  45
```

Hope this helps.

The main issue, that I hope no idea what this type of query is being called in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such cases you can use a **[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)** as in @robinhood's answer. Alternatively you can use **[`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)**. And if you are going to do these operations for more than one column, we can save the processed dataframes to a list with the help of a loop:

```
fields = ['COL2','COL3']
final_dataframes=[]
for i in fields:
    dfx=pd.crosstab(df[i], df['COL1'], values=df['COL4'],aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
    dfx['Grand Total']=dfx['aaa'] + dfx['bbb']
    final_dataframes.append(dfx)

print(final_dataframes[0]) # for example, get first dataframe.
'''
        aaa   bbb  Grand Total
COL2                          
a1234   5.0   0.0          5.0
a2345  10.0   0.0         10.0
a3456  15.0   0.0         15.0
a5678  20.0  25.0         45.0
'''
```

We can do all these operations in two lines:

```
final_dataframes=[pd.crosstab(df[i], df['COL1'], values=df['COL4'],aggfunc='sum').fillna(0) for i in fields]
final_dataframes=[i.assign(Grand_Total=(i['aaa'] + i['bbb'])) for i in final_dataframes]
```

Answer (score 1):

For this I would suggest the pivot_table function from pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
result =  pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'COL2', columns="COL1",values="COL4",aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
```

For the grand total, you can then use

```
result["grand_total"] = result["aaa"] + result["bbb"]
```